# Modulus with negative numbers in C++

Tags: c++, modulo, recurrence

I have been writing a program for the following recurrence relation:

```
An = 5An-1 - 2An-2  - An-3 + An-4
```

The output should be the Answer modulus 10^9 + 7..
I wrote a brute force approach for this one as follows...

```
long long int t1=5, t2=9, t3=11, t4=13, sum;
while(i--)
{
    sum=((5*t4) - 2*t3 - t2 +t1)%MOD;
    t1=t2;
    t2=t3;
    t3=t4;
    t4=sum;
}
printf("%lld\n", sum);
```

where `MOD= 10^9 +7` 
Every thing seems to be true.. but i am getting negative answer for some values.. and due to this problem, I am unable to find the correct solution... 
Plz help about the right place to keep the `Modulus`

Comment: Shouldn't you use `unsigned long long` for `sum`?

Comment: @Alex1985 it wouldn't make any difference if the `%` operator always returned a positive value, but since it sometimes gives a negative result, signed variables should be used.

Comment: @Hurkyl- you're right. Comment removed.

Comment: [Does either ANSI C or ISO C specify what -5 % 10 should be?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3609572/995714), [Modulo operation with negative numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11720656/995714), [Why is the behavior of the modulo operator (%) different between C and Ruby for negative integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24074869/995714)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The thing is that the % operator isn't the "modulo operator" but the "division remainder" operator with the following equality

```
(a/b)*b + a%b == a    (for b!=0)
```

So, if in case your integer division rounds towards zero (which is mandated since C99 and C++11, I think), -5/4 will be -1 and we have

```
(-5/4)*4 + -5%4 == -5
  -1  *4    -1  == -5
```

In order to get a positive result (for the modulo operation) you need to add the divisor in case the remainder was negative or do something like this:

```
long mod(long a, long b)
{ return (a%b+b)%b; }
```

Answer (score 12):

Using `%` a second time in @sellibitze's and @liquidblueocean's answers probably won't be as slow as `%` tends to be in general, because it boils down to either one subtraction of `b` or none. Actually, let me just check that...

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a = argc;    //Various tricks to prevent the
    int b = 7;       //compiler from optimising things out.
    int c[10];       //Using g++ 4.8.1
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000111000; ++i)
        c[a % b] = 3;
        //c[a < b ? a : a-b] = 3;
    return a;
}
```

Alternatively commenting the line with `%` or the other line, we get:

- With `%`: 14 seconds
- With `?`: 7 seconds

So `%` is not as optimised as I suspected. Probably because that optimisation would add overhead.

Therefore, it's better to not use `%` twice, for performance reasons.

Instead, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1082938/1143274) suggests and explains, do this:

```
int mod(int k, int n) {
    return ((k %= n) < 0) ? k+n : k;
}
```

It takes [a bit more work if you want it to work properly for negative `n` too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20924698/1143274), but that's almost never necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Just replace `%` by a function that handles negative values:

```
long long int mod(long long int a, long long int b) {
    long long int ret = a % b;
    if (ret < 0)
        ret += b;
    return ret;
}
```

EDIT: Changed the data type to `long long int`.

Answer (score 4):

All answers currently here that have a once-off addition in their formula are wrong when abs(a) > b. Use this or similar:

```
int modulo (int a, int b) { return a >= 0 ? a % b : ( b - abs ( a%b ) ) % b; }
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said `%` is just a remainder operator rather than `mod`. However, the mod/remainder operation distributes correctly through recurrence relations like this, so if you just adjust your final solution to be positive, like this,

```
if (sum < 0) { sum = sum + MOD; }
```

then you should get the right answer. The advantage of doing it this way is that you introduce one less function call and/or branch per loop iteration. (Which may or may not matter depending on how clever your compiler is).

Comment: Note you can solve this in `O(log(N))` time if you use modular matrix exponentiation rather than using the recurrence relation directly (which is `O(N)`).