# Expression involving modular exponentiations in C++

Tags: c++, modular, exponentiation

I am wanting to evaluate the expression, `(an + bn + cn) % 1000000003` , in C++. I a getting overflow errors when n is very large. Can someone help me with this ? More specifically `a = q + 1, b = - 2 * q` and `c = q - 1`. I have been following the function outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207006/modular-exponentiation-for-high-numbers-in-c)

Can I break `(an + bn + cn) % 1000000003` into `(an) % 1000000003 + (bn) % 100000003 + (cn) % 1000000003` or something similar ? 
Also I cannot use anything more than **unsigned long long int**

Comment: ^ is raised to the power!

Comment: @MayankJha:  Not in C++ it isn't.  In C++ `^` means XOR.

Comment: It's more of a math question now.

Comment: @MayankJha Your welcome to SO, please [view edits I made](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19276945/revisions) because `^` was confusing as XOR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can distribute your modulo. Mathematically, this will be sound:

```
( ((a^n)%1000000003) + ((b^n)%100000003) + ((c^n)%1000000003) ) % 1000000003;
```

This will prevent you from having to compute numbers that are out of bounds, allowing you to choose larger values for `n`.

[Proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Modulo_Addition_is_Commutative).

Just be sure to use `pow` in the `math.h` module:

```
( ((pow(a, n))%1000000003) 
    + ((pow(b, n))%100000003) 
    + ((pow(c, n))%1000000003) ) % 1000000003;
```

Comment: but as you can see b is negative won't this cause erroneous results ?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276675/modulus-with-negative-numbers-in-c). If you don't want negatives, handle them in your code! :)

Comment: I dont think this would work if `n` is very large say 1000000000

Comment: using `pow` can cause precision errors, I am using Modular Exponentiation. Will the identity you've written still work if I am applying modular exponentiation ?

Comment: Yes, it should still work with Modular Exponentiation. All this does is reduce the overhead on number storage size.