# Wrapping around a grid with modulo

Tags: c++, algorithm, modulo, cellular-automata

I am trying to write a program that implements Conway's Game of Life on a grid of 20x60 cells. The grid should wrap around so that the left side is connected to the right side and the top is connected to the bottom.

Thus, any cell with position `(0, col)`, will have a neighbour at `(maxRow, col)`. Any cell with position `(row, 0)` will have a neighbour at `(row, maxCol)`.

The following function is supposed to count the number of neighbouring cells. It works for coordinates not on the edges, but not for ones that are. For instance, if there are points at `(0, 10)`, `(0, 11)`, `(0, 12)`, and `(0, 10)` is passed into the function, it will return a high number as neighbour count instead of `1`. I know that the mod operator `%` would be helpful, but I don't understand how to use it.

```
{
    int i, j;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; i++)
       for (j = col - 1; j <= col + 1; j++) 
           count += grid[i][j]; }

    if (row==maxrow-1 || row==0)
         count = count+ grid [(row-(maxrow-1))*-1][col-1]+grid[(row-(maxrow-1))*-1][col]+grid[(row-(maxrow-1))*-1][col+1];

    if (col==0 || col==maxcol-1)
         count=count +grid[row-1][(col-(maxcol-1))*-1]+grid[row][(col-(maxcol-1))*-1]+grid[row+1][(col-(maxcol-1))*-1];



    count -= grid[row][col];
    return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Before offering a solution, let me make some observations.

- Adding up some grid values and later subtracting other grid values is not a good idea. You should calculate the correct grid coordinates to begin with.
- When you write `count += grid[i][j];`, you are using array indices that may be invalid. For example, `i = row - 1` when `row` is zero yields an `i` value of `-1`.
- Your code implies that `maxrow` is the number of rows because you're writing `maxrow-1`, but the name `maxrow` suggests a maximum row index. This is confusing. It would be better to call the number of rows `numRows`, and then the greatest row index is `numRows - 1`. Likewise, it would be better to replace `maxcol` with `numCols`.

Now to the heart of the matter. The value `row - 1` can be equal to `-1`, and `row + 1` can be equal to `numRows`. Both of these are invalid row indices. Similarly, `col - 1` and `col + 1` can result in the invalid column indices `-1` and `numCols`. One way to solve the problem is to test for these particular values and replace them with wraparound indices:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; i++) {
  int R = i;
  if (R == -1) {
    R = numRows - 1;
  } else if (R == numRows) {
    R = 0;
  }
  for (int j = col - 1; j <= col + 1; j++) {
    if (i == row && j == col) {
      continue;  // Skip grid[row][col].
    }
    int C = j;
    if (C == -1) {
      C = numCols - 1;
    } else if (C == numCols) {
      C = 0;
    }
    count += grid[R][C];
  }
}
```

That's a high-performance way to solve the problem because testing and assignment are faster operations than modulo, but it's also a lot of code. We can write more concise code with the help of the modulo operator.

We would like to write `i % numRows`, except C++ evaluates this as -1 when `i` is -1. That's because the modulo operation is ambiguous for negative values and [C++ has chosen an interpretation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630321/why-does-c-output-negative-numbers-when-using-modulo) that doesn't guarantee non-negative results.

To fix this problem, we add `numRows` to `i` before taking the modulo `numRows`. This ensures that we're always taking the modulo of a positive number. Now we can count the number of live cells among the eight neighbors of `grid[row][col]` as follows.

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; i++) {
  for (int j = col - 1; j <= col + 1; j++) {
    if (i == row && j == col) { 
      continue;  // Skip grid[row][col].
    }
    count += grid[(i + numRows) % numRows][(j + numCols) % numCols];
  }
}
```