# Modulo of negative integers in Go

Tags: go, modulo

I am learning Go and I come from a Python background.

Recently, I stumbled onto a behaviour of the `%`(modulo) operator which is different from the corresponding operator in Python. Quite contrary to the definition of [modular operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) and remainder, the modulus of negative integers by a positive integer returns a negative value.

Example:

#### Python

```
a, b, n = -5, 5, 3
for i in range(a, b):
    print(i%n)
```

Output:

```
1
2
0
1
2
0
1
2
0
1
```

#### Go

```
a, b, n := -5, 5, 3
for i:=a; i<b; i++ {
    fmt.Println(i%n)
}
```

Output:

```
-2
-1
0
-2
-1
0
1
2
0
1
```

After reading about the [Modulo operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519845/modulo-of-a-negative-number) and few similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630321/why-does-c-output-negative-numbers-when-using-modulo) asked about the reason behind these differences, I understand that these were due to design goals of the concerned languages.

Is there a built-in functionality in Go which replicates the modulus operation of Python?

Alternate: Is there an internal method for computing the "modulus" instead of the "remainder"?

Answer (score 19):

See [this comment by one of the language designers](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/448#issuecomment-66049769):

> There are a several reasons for the current definition:
>
> - the current semantics for % is directly available as a result from x86 architectures
> - it would be confusing to change the meaning of the elementary operator % and not change its name
> - it's fairly easy to compute another modulus from the % result
>
> Note that % computes the "remainder" as opposed to the "modulus".

There is not an operator or function in the standard library which replicates the modulus operation of Python.

It is possible to write a function which replicates the modulus operation of Python:

```go
func modLikePython(d, m int) int {
   var res int = d % m
   if ((res < 0 && m > 0) || (res > 0 && m < 0)) {
      return res + m
   }
   return res
}
```

Note that in Python `5 % -3` is `-1` and this code replicates that behavior as well. If you don't want that, remove the second part after `||` in the `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. This issue slipped from me since it is closed.
I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: You can simplify your Go to Python Modulus code to just:  `(i % n) + n) % n`. Verified [here](https://play.golang.org/p/QT5PA9fltU)

Answer (score 19):

If you want a Go function that implements Python's modulo behaviour, try this:

```
func mod(a, b int) int {
    return (a % b + b) % b
}
```

If you'd like an explanation of modulo vs. remainder, read on.

By nearly all definitions of modulo, it is the remainder after division. In other words, modulo vs. remainder is a false dichotomy because they're the same thing.

Distinctions arise because there's more than one sensible way of defining a remainder, where different definitions give distinct results.

For example, consider 11 divided by 5, with a true quotient of 2.2. In the context of integers, there's more than one way to interpret this:

- Quotient of 2 and remainder of 1
- Quotient of 3 and remainder of -4

And for negative 11 divided by 5:

- Quotient of -2 and remainder of -1
- Quotient of -3 and remainder of 4

There's a few ways to specify which remainder we want. For example, by choosing how we round the true quotient to find the integer quotient (round up, round down, round towards zero). Maybe the simplest way is by choosing what sign we want the remainder to have (when it's non-zero). For example, we could say that the remainder `a mod b` should have the same sign as `a`. This is how Go's `%` operator works. You could also say that the remainder `a mod b` should have the same sign as `b`. This is how Python's `%` operator works.

Wikipedia has a breakdown of some [various definitions of modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo#Variants_of_the_definition), as well as a [list of programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo#In_programming_languages) labelled by which definition they use.

Answer (score 0):

`math/big` does Euclidean modulus:

```golang
package main
import "math/big"

func mod(x, y int64) int64 {
   bx, by := big.NewInt(x), big.NewInt(y)
   return new(big.Int).Mod(bx, by).Int64()
}

func main() {
   z := mod(-5, 3)
   println(z == 1)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/math/big#Int.Mod

Answer (score 0):

On Q2, you could use:

```
func modNeg(v, m int) int {
    return (v%m + m) % m
}
```

Would output:

```
modNeg(-1, 5) => 4
modNeg(-2, 3) => 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, just add the second number to the result:

Python:

```py
-8%6 => 4
```

Golang:

```golang
-8%6 + 6 => 4
```

So the function will be like this:

```golang
func PyMod(d int, m int) int {
  d %= m
  if d < 0 { 
    d += m
  }
  return d
}
```

It works for some other situations such as `a%-b` in addition to `-a%b`.

But if you want it to work even for `-a%-b`, do like this:

```golang
func PyMod(d int, m int) int {
  // Add this condition at the top
  if d < 0 && m < 0 {
    return d % m
  } 
  d %= m
  if d < 0 { 
    d += m
  }
  return d
}
```