# Which is the correct way to determine if two numbers have the same parity?

Tags: c++, numbers, parity

I found two solutions to find out if two numbers have the same parity (both are odd numbers or both are even). In C++, they look like this:

```
if ((a+b)%2 == 0)
```

and

```
if (a%2 == b%2)
```

The problem is that the first one works on 100% of cases and the second one only on 80% of the cases (the tests of a problem that I have submitted on a website) and I do not understand why. For me, both lines of code should work fine on all cases. Can somebody explain me why does the first line of code work in all cases and the second one does not? And which method (those showed by me or another) would you recommend?

Comment: Can you provide a test case where #2 does not work?

Comment: I am not allowed to see the tests on this problem and I could not find any cases on paper on which the second statement does not work.

Comment: What types are `a` and `b`?

Comment: I think the problem must be in code you haven't posted. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Try with negatives and positive/negative mixes.

Comment: @Yunnosch: I bet that's it.

Comment: @Yunnosch, I have tried and I can not see anything wrong in both cases.

Comment: @FredLarson, this is the problem that I am talking about: [link](https://www.pbinfo.ro/?pagina=probleme&id=1366)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, they are of the type int.

Comment: I found differences. For example, -49943 8833.

Comment: Right.  And what result do you get when you take the remainder of a negative number?

Comment: @FredLarson, if I use your example I do not see anything wrong. `-49943 % 2 = 1` and `8833 % 2 = 1`, so both numbers have the same parity and if I sum up them, I get `-49943 + 8833 = -41110`. `-41110 % 2 = 0`, so, again, they have the same parity.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, the remainder is a positive number.

Comment: Are you computing that, or is C++ computing that? I get `-49943%2 == -1`.

Comment: Nope.  It is unspecified in the language if it is negative or positive.  On many hardware platforms, including x86, it will be a negative number.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11630321/10077

Comment: Thanks for the information! It is very useful. But if you sum the numbers in your example, you also get a negative number, so even my first line of code (which worked on all tests) should not work in this case.

Comment: Only if it's odd, and then the sign doesn't matter in the first case. -1 is still not 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would not recommend either of the methods in your post, you should use one of these instead:

```
if ((a & 1) == (b & 1)) {} // this is clearer

if (((a ^ b) & 1) == 0) {} // this is faster

if (!((a ^ b) & 1)) {}     // this is as fast as faster
```

These depend on the fact that bit 0 will be set for odd values, even if negative.  Avoid integer division (and modulo) whenever possible, it's one of the slowest instructions on any CPU.