# Why does the following program gives wrong answer when I remove "+ mod" from statement check . Problem link: https://www.codechef.com/problems/FFC219B

Tags: c++

The statement check is where I don't understand why it shows wrong answer on submission when I write "sum = (solution[R]-solution[L-1])%mod;" instead. Here I have not added mod within the bracket. I don't see how the answer changes by adding a value of taking the mod of same. Problem code in codechef: https://www.codechef.com/problems/FFC219B

```
#include<iostream>
#define ll long long
#define mod 1000000007   //the modulus we need to take for the final answer
#define endl "\n"
using namespace std;

long long solution[100007] = {0}; //Initialising all the values with zero

int main(){

ios_base :: sync_with_stdio(0);

cin.tie(0);

cout.tie(0);

solution[0] = 0;

ll a1=1,a2=2,a3=3,a4=4;    //The variable initialising as per the problem

 for(int i = 1;i <= 100007;i++){

     ll k=(a1 * a2) % mod * a3 % mod * a4 % mod;

        solution[i] = (solution[i-1]+k)%mod;  //Adding the previous values as we are to find the sum in range

        a1++;

        a2++;

        a3++;

        a4++;
     }

    int t; //Taking input for number of test cases

    cin>>t;

    while(t-->0)
    {

        int L,R;

        cin>>L>>R; //Taking the range input

        long long sum = 0;

        sum = (solution[R]-solution[L-1] + mod)%mod; //statement check & final answer

        cout<<sum<<endl;

       }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Already used my vote, so unfortunately cannot now close as a duplicate of [Why does C++ output negative numbers when using modulo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630321/why-does-c-output-negative-numbers-when-using-modulo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program can give the incorrect answer since the correct answer must always be a positive - not a negative - number.

When you subtract consecutive modulo values, the result may well be negative even though the numbers themselves are increasing (eg, (4^3)%10 - (4^2)%10 = 64%10 - 16%10 = 4-6 = -2), .  This means “solution[R]-solution[L-1]” may also well be negative, which means “(solution[R]-solution[L-1]) % mod” will also be negative - although clearly the answer (the number of people affected) must always be positive.

So adding the mod value in this fashion ensures that the result will always be positive.